# Why am i getting error SSL routines:SSL_write:bad length

Tags: openssl

When i'm using openssl trying to connect with server, handshake mechanism is success and i could see the same in wireshark whereas when i request for "GET /" http method to server, server accepts the command-  i could see an [ACK] from server but secure connection is terminated abruptply with below error surprisingly from the client - I don't understand why such an error is thrown from openssl.

Can't use **SSL_get_servername\r\n17476:error:140D010F:SSL routines:SSL_write:bad length**:../openssl-1.1.1c/ssl/ssl_lib.c:1953:\r\n

ALERT WARNING - CLOSE_NOTIFY